# What "option" to use with "WGET" for selecting only few files with particular extension from a FTP directory

Tags: file, ftp, wget

I am trying to download files with particular datestamp as an extension from a folder through FTP server. Since the folder contains all other files, I wanted to download only files with a particular datestamp.

I tried using `wget files_datestamp*.extension`, which didn't work.
I also tried using `wget -i files_datestamp*.extension`, which downloads all.

My question is: What option to use with `wget` to download only particular files that I am interested in?

```
wget  http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/cmc/CMOI/NetCDF/NMME/1p0deg/#%23%23/CanCM3_201904_r4i1p1_20190501*.nc4
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you've shared is over HTTP and not FTP. As a result, it is not possible to glob over the filenames, that is feasible only over FTP.

With HTTP, it is imperative that you have access to a directory listing page which tells you which files are available. Then use `-r --accept-regex=<regex here>` to download your files